# Let $z_0$ be an essential singularity of $f^2$,then show that $z_0$ is an essential singularity of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Let $z_0$ be an essential singularity of $f$,then show that $z_0$ is an essential singularity of $f^2$.

**TRY**:

If $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f^2$ then by Riemann's Singularity Theorrem $f^2$ is bounded in a deleted neighbourhood of $z_0\implies f$ is bounded in a deleted neighbourhood of $z_0$ which is false.

Now if  $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$ of $f^2\implies f^2(z)=\dfrac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$ where $\phi$ is analytic at $z_0$.

> How to show from here that $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$?If I show this then 
>   only then I can show that $z_0$ is an essential singularity of $f^2$.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are allmost there, show that $z_0$ is neither a removable singularity of $f^2$ and $1/f^2$, you have the argument for $f^2$ it is the same for $1/f^2$.

Comment: But can't I do it as I have done by showing it is not a pole of $f^2$

Comment: If $\frac{1}{f}$ is bounded in  a deleted neighbourhood of $z_0$ how does it imply that $f$ is bounded in a del. ngbd of $z_0$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity

Comment: Yes okay for the article in wiki, but how to show that $\dfrac{1}{f}$ has a removable singularity.please help

Comment: suppose $z_0$ is the removable singularity $lim_{z \to z_0}f$ exists. Hence, $lim_{z \to z_0}f^2$. which is a contradiction. suppose $z_0$ is a pole $lim_{z \to z_0}f=\infty$ . Hence, $lim_{z \to z_0}f^2=\infty$. which is a contradiction. So, $z_0$ must be essential. Am I correct? @TsemoAristide

Comment: Can I do argument like this?